# Jquery + ADF - Localização de Botões

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

uso ADF e estou com um problema.

No caso eu tenho um popup na sequencia um dialog e apos um panelgroup, abaixo do panelgroup criei um facet "buttonBar" logo eu tenho um estilo definido no meu popup porém eu preciso usar uma skin nos botões abaixo, o problema é que eles ficam com o style setado acima e não os que seto nos botões de fato. Neste contexto eu estou usando um jquery que detecta a tecla enter, pois preciso que o enter se comporte como um clic(por isso o facet).
A duvida é, eu preciso que meus botões assumam meu style e que meu jquery detecte meu enter, mesmo que ambos fiquem em camadas diferentes (Se for o caso). Segue o código:

```
<af:popup animate="default" childCreation="immediate" autoCancel="enabled"  id="p2">
          <af:dialog closeIconVisible="false"  contentHeight="300" contentWidth="300" 
                     title="TITULO" id="d122" resize="off" modal="true" type="none">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block"  id="formfwfiltro" styleClass="estilo-exemplo-dois">
                        <h:panelGroup id="dialogContainer" layout="block" styleClass="estilo-exemplo">
                            <af:group id="tablecontainer">
                                    <!-- CONTEÚDO -->
                            </af:group>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>
            <f:facet name="buttonBar">
            <af:group id="buttonbargroup">
                  <af:commandButton  text="#{pageFlowScope.exemplo}" id="formfwbtnaction" partialSubmit="false" 
                                     visible="true" styleClass="class-style-exemplo" action="#{pageFlowScope.exemplo}" />
            </af:group>
            </f:facet>
                 <trh:script id="scriptfiltro">
                        <![CDATA[
                          $(document).ready(function () {
                            buscaenteresc();
                          });
                        ]]>
                 </trh:script>
            </af:dialog>   
</af:popup>
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar alguma parte do seu código? Assim ficaria mais fácil de auxiliarmos você...

Comment: Opa, claro que sim, montei aqui na corrida um exemplo, espero que esteja compreensível hehe.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar vê se o código ajuda, hehe. Obrigado.